# SpriteKit GameScene function won't add SKSpriteNode after being called by button

Tags: swift, projectile

I checked that the fireLaser() function is called as it can be accessed and print out to console but the laser is never added to the scene. If I copy and paste the code in the fireLaser() function it works in the didMoveToView() function.

```
let character = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "monkey")
let laser = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet_yellow")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    var background : SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "space.png")
    background.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2)
    background.size = self.frame.size
    self.addChild(background)
    character.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.25)
    addChild(character)

//Shoots Laser From Character
func fireLaser(){
    laser.position = character.position
    addChild(laser)
    let laserDestination = CGPoint(x: character.position.x, y: self.size.height)
    let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(laserDestination, duration: 2.0)
    let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    laser.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))
    println ("check")
}
```

//FROM GAME VIEW CONTROLLER

```
@IBAction func firePressed(){
    GameScene().fireLaser()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part:

```
@IBAction func firePressed(){
    GameScene().fireLaser()
}
```

... do you mean to instantiate a new `GameScene` and call `fireLaser()` on it right away?  Without probably presenting the scene in the SKView first?

What I think is happening is that whenever a button is pressed you run `firePressed()` method, which would create a new instance of GameScene object (`GameScene()` part), run `fireLaser()` method on that instance, and then be done with it.  Problem is, it is *another* game scene, that is, not the one you have in your SKView.

Instead you should run `fireLaser()` on the scene that is *already* there.

E.g. something like:

```
@IBAction func firePressed(){
    skView.scene?.fireLaser()
}
```

Comment: Well i added a button on the game view controller which i wanted as a firing button where my sprite shoots a projectile whenever its pressed, is this the best way to do this?

Comment: I was not clear enough in my reply.  I edited it, please have a look.

Comment: Sorry, Im new to spritekit but when i copy and replace my code with skView.scene?.fireLaser(), an error occurs "use of unresolved identifier skView"

Comment: `skView` was just an example. You should use the name of outlet in your view controller that you created (or should create) for SKView.